# How to allow text to be copied from wordpad to my Java Swing app?

Tags: java, text, copy

I took it for granted that if I have a wordpad on my left side of screen, and my Java Swing app with a JTextfield on the right side of screen, I can copy text using ctrl-C from the wordpad then ctrl-V the text into the Java Swing app's JTextfiled, but nothing happens.

I've recently replaced the hard drive, and installed Win7, Java ... so I'm not sure this behavior is because I've re-installed everything, or it is like this as normal, what should I do to enable text copy and paste ?

Comment: You should be able to copy-paste from another application into a JTextField. What version of Java are you using? What are you trying to copy-paste? This question may apply if you're copying certain special characters (it looks like it was a bug that was fixed with Java 8): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028598/java-swing-jtextfield-jtextarea-unable-to-paste-supplemental-unicode-character

Comment: This is definitely not normal, pasting should work. Have you tried pasting simple plaintext e.g. from notepad?

Comment: But, just to be clear, if you write on the textfield, the text appears?

Comment: Using Java 8, trying to copy-paste "123","abc", simple text, I can copy-paste inside notepad/wordpad, and inside different fields inside Java app, and copy text from Java textfield then paste into wordpad, but not able to copy text from wordpad then paste into Java app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found the answer :

```
[1] Original app was compiled into a jar file, the jar file was doing copy-paste correctly either direction
[2] But the jar file can't be pined to the taskbar
[3] So I used exe4j to compile it into an exe file to be able to pin to the tackbar
[4] The result exe file can't do copy-paste correctly [ exe4j issue ]
[5] I found a way to pin jar file to the taskbar through a javaw.exe -jar *.jar shortcut,and pin that shortcut to the taskbar
```